# XPath: next child of parent

Tags: php, html, xpath

I'm trying to get child of parent using Xpath in php.

Html:

```
<div class="Grid Grid--multiCol Grid--2to3 Grid--gutterH20px">
    <div class="Grid-cell Grid-cell--1">
        <span class="u-colorVehicleAttrs">Body:</span>
    </div>
    <div class="Grid-cell Grid-cell--2">Sport Utility Vehicle (SUV)/Multi Purpose Vehicle (MPV)</div>
</div>
```

Php:

```
...
$bodytype = $my_xpath->query("//span[text()='Body:']/following-sibling::div[1]")[0]->nodeValue;
echo $bodytype;
```

So, what sequence I'm looking for:

1. Find span with text "Body:"
2. Get text of div next to parent element of current node --> result of echo should be "Sport Utility Vehicle (SUV)/Multi Purpose Vehicle (MPV)"

P.S.: class names are not unique and used for many other lines, so accessing by attribute is not the case.

Hope the question is clearly explained :) Thank you.

Comment: To solve this using your approach, just go up one level: `"//span[text()='Body:']/../following-sibling::div[1]"`

Comment: Thank you, code-kobold! It works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Get text of div next to *parent element* of current node

Your xpath, however, attempts to get following-siblings of *current node*.

So, fixing that, the xpath becomes: `//span[text()="Body:"]/../following-sibling::div[1]`